# Java 8 Nashorn - capturing engine.eval("print('hello world')) into String object?

Tags: java, java-8, nashorn

Is there a way to capture the result of print('hello world') inside Nashorn and place it in a String object.

I have tried this:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(baos, true);
System.setOut(ps);

String result = (String)engine.eval("print('hello world')");

if (result != null) {
    System.out.println(result);
} else {
    System.out.println(baos.toString());
}
```

When engine evaluates this javascript it just prints to stdout so I figured I just redirect stdout to my own OutputStream and then convert it to String, but it doesn't work.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are setting the `System.out` stream *after* you have created your engine so it’s very likely that the engine’s context has already recorded the value of `System.out`/`System.err` at construction time.

Therefore you still see the output of the script on the console. Even worse, you don’t see the output of your own later-on `System.out.println` anymore as you have redirected `System.out` to your `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

So don’t modify `System.out`, instead change the output in the context of your scripting engine `engine.`[`getContext()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptEngine.html#getContext--)`.`[`setWriter(`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/script/ScriptContext.html#setWriter-java.io.Writer-)`stringWriter)`.

Complete code:

```
StringWriter sw=new StringWriter();
engine.getContext().setWriter(sw);
String result = (String)engine.eval("print('hello world')");
System.out.println("Result returned by eval(): "+result);
System.out.println("Captured output: "+sw);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is with:

```
if (result != null)
```

Evaluating the `print(...)` statement will still give you the return value of `print`, which is probably `undefined`. But my guess is that you still have the right stuff in `baos`, and if you changed your statement to `if (false)` it would work as expected.

That said, this may not be the best way to do this, depending what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to cast the eval result - that would be JS undefined value. After you set Writer instance for the current ScriptContext, you eval code that writes by print. And then pick up accumulated strings from the Writer instance. (StringWriter's toString would give you that String).